# Mule internal lifecycle - what all happens when we start mule

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am unable to find any documentation on what happens when we start mule ESB (standalone). On looking inside the mule Java wrapper that gets called, it calls the launcher which calls the Groovy based initializer. But what happens after that is little tough to trace.

I looked at the [API docs](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.5.0/apidocs/). It would be nice & helpful for whole community, if some one can point to any document on lifecycle events of mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule uses the [tanuki wrapper](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Understanding+the+Java+Service+Wrapper) to control the Java process. After that, I would recommend looking at the [Mule class loading page](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Classloader+Control+in+Mule) to understand the order with which Mule loads classes at runtime.

HTH